# Django generic query builder

Tags: python, django

I have a lot of models in my Django project, and many of them need their own queries for specific pages. While working on the seperation of concerns, I feel like there should be a way to make one (or very few) methods that are generic enough and work with input based to work as queries for ALL models.

Say I have model A B and C and I have the following sets of queries:

```
A.objects.filter(id=object_id)
A.objects.filter(id=object_id).values("id", "name")
A.objects.filter(name="test")
B.objects.filter(relationA=A)
B.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_ids)
C.objects.all()
C.objects.all().exclude('last_name')
```

Is there any way to create a query by a given:

- Model Name (A, B, C)
- filter type (possibly, least important if this isn't doable? filter, all)
- comparison field (id, name, relation)
- comparison type (x=x, x__in=list, x__lte=10)
- comparison value (object_id, "test", list_of_ids)

So for example, X being dynamic parts would result in a function (Pseudocode) like:

```
def query(model, filter_type, comparison_field, comparison_type, comparison_value):
    #X.objects.X(X=X)
    return model.objects.filter_type(comparison_field + comparison=comparison_value)
```

When trying it briefly, I immediately ran into the issue of comparison_field not doing what I need it to. Seeing Q objects being mentioned a lot on SO, are they something I should be applying here? and if so, how?

**Edit:
As suggested by Klaus D. , I've implemented kwargs with a dynamic dictionary.**

query_manager.py

```
def make_query_kwargs(kwargs_dict, field, value):
    kwargs_dict[field] = value
    return kwargs_dict


def make_object_query(model, kwargs, columns=[]):
    return model.objects.filter(**kwargs).values(*columns)
```

Which I use by doing the following:

```
kwargs = {}
id_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
kwargs = query_manager.make_query_kwargs(kwargs, "id__in", id_list)
query_result = query_manager.make_object_query(A, kwargs)
```

Comment: Construct a dictionary with the query you like and use the `**` keyword argument expansion.

Comment: Thanks! this already solved so much for this 'issue'. Now only need to find a way to constructing the dictionary in a neat way. Will update my post with what I've done.

Comment: May I kindly suggest that [this won't really improve your code readability](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Rube_Goldberg%27s_%22Self-Operating_Napkin%22_%28cropped%29.gif) ?

Comment: True to some extent, I haven't decided if I'm using it either. But knowing its possible and learning from it is important, and now I'm debating if its actually better. So for example: 1 Generic method that does all filter queries, or would you rather have a total of 50 specific methods if you tally up all methods for each model.